# Apple Magic Trackpad 1 - 'stops working' every few minutes

Tags: touchpad, bluetooth, intel, intel-nuc

I have just purchased an Apple Magic Trackpad 1 and connected it to my Ubuntu 15.10 (now 16.04) system. That all worked flawlessly.

Once connected, the trackpad 'stops working' every few minutes. I don't know if it is getting disconnected from Bluetooth or powering itself off. All I know is that I can get it working again by pressing the power button on the trackpad. Sometimes I have to do it twice or even three times, but then it will work again.

I have tried the usual things like changing the batteries, deleting it from bluetooth and adding it again. rebooting my system and re-adding it.

If I leave the device connected overnight, when I come back to it in the morning, touching the trackpad will wake up the system.

`> lsusb`

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 058f:3820 Alcor Micro Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`> dmesg | grep -i blue`

```
[    7.737943] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[    7.737965] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    7.737971] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    7.737974] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    7.737981] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    7.801692] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e0f
[    7.801696] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel device is already patched. patch num: 0f
[    8.511238] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    8.511242] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    8.511249] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   10.685841] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   10.685852] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   10.685859] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   16.697130] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[   16.697139] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
[   16.704913] input: Apple Wireless Trackpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:05AC:030E.0006/input/input16
[   16.707549] magicmouse 0005:05AC:030E.0006: input,hidraw3: BLUETOOTH HID v1.60 Mouse [Apple Wireless Trackpad] on dc:53:60:ce:be:17
[10034.751891] input: Apple Wireless Trackpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:05AC:030E.0007/input/input17
[10034.752119] magicmouse 0005:05AC:030E.0007: input,hidraw3: BLUETOOTH HID v1.60 Mouse [Apple Wireless Trackpad] on dc:53:60:ce:be:17
[36234.802293] input: Apple Wireless Trackpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:05AC:030E.0008/input/input18
[36234.803791] magicmouse 0005:05AC:030E.0008: input,hidraw3: BLUETOOTH HID v1.60 Mouse [Apple Wireless Trackpad] on dc:53:60:ce:be:17
[39265.445927] input: Apple Wireless Trackpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:05AC:030E.0009/input/input19
[39265.446146] magicmouse 0005:05AC:030E.0009: input,hidraw3: BLUETOOTH HID v1.60 Mouse [Apple Wireless Trackpad] on dc:53:60:ce:be:17
[42890.060268] input: Apple Wireless Trackpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:05AC:030E.000A/input/input20
[42890.060495] magicmouse 0005:05AC:030E.000A: input,hidraw3: BLUETOOTH HID v1.60 Mouse [Apple Wireless Trackpad] on dc:53:60:ce:be:17
[61297.037662] input: Apple Wireless Trackpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:05AC:030E.000B/input/input22  
[61297.038420] magicmouse 0005:05AC:030E.000B: input,hidraw3: BLUETOOTH HID v1.60 Mouse [Apple Wireless Trackpad] on dc:53:60:ce:be:17
[63833.172707] Modules linked in: algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg cmac hid_magicmouse hidp drbg ansi_cprng ctr ccm rfcomm bnep nls_iso8859_1 intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm arc4 crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul aesni_intel iwlmvm aes_x86_64 lrw snd_soc_rt5640 gf128mul glue_helper snd_hda_codec_realtek ablk_helper cryptd snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_codec_hdmi mac80211 btusb snd_soc_rl6231 snd_hda_intel btrtl snd_usb_audio snd_hda_codec btbcm uvcvideo snd_usbmidi_lib snd_soc_core videobuf2_vmalloc serio_raw joydev videobuf2_memops input_leds btintel snd_compress snd_hda_core videobuf2_core ac97_bus v4l2_common snd_hwdep snd_pcm_dmaengine iwlwifi videodev bluetooth ir_lirc_codec media snd_pcm lirc_dev cfg80211 ir_sanyo_decoder ir_xmp_decoder ir_mce_kbd_decoder ir_sharp_decoder
```

`> lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:9010]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

`sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi`

```
[    7.681317] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    7.683533] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[    7.685661] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.685685] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.685699] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.694346] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    7.759241] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[    7.759597] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    7.760054] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    8.006650] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[    8.792452] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    8.793061] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    8.854205] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    8.854757] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[96297.700161] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: invalid BA notification: Q 16, tid 0, flow 65535
[240874.957686] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: invalid BA notification: Q 16, tid 0, flow 65535
```

`sudo strace -p 727`

```
  read(3, 0x7ffef8cb63f0, 16)             = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
    write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
    read(7, "\f\0\0\0\10\0\2028\355\337c\210\0\1", 512) = 14
    write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
    poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}, {fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=16, events=POLLIN}, {fd=17, events=POLLIN}, {fd=18, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=20, events=POLLIN}, {fd=21, events=0}, {fd=22, events=0}], 18, 0) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
    sendmsg(6, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(2)=[{"l\4\1\1<\0\0\0\217\0\0\0\206\0\0\0\1\1o\0%\0\0\0/org/blu"..., 152}, {"\21\0\0\0org.bluez.Device1\0\0\0\30\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 60}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 212
    poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}, {fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=16, events=POLLIN}, {fd=17, events=POLLIN}, {fd=18, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=20, events=POLLIN}, {fd=21, events=0}, {fd=22, events=0}], 18, -1) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
    read(3, "\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16)         = 8
    poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}, {fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=16, events=POLLIN}, {fd=17, events=POLLIN}, {fd=18, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=20, events=POLLIN}, {fd=21, events=0}, {fd=22, events=0}], 18, -1) = 2 ([{fd=21, revents=POLLERR|POLLHUP}, {fd=22, revents=POLLERR|POLLHUP}])
    read(3, 0x7ffef8cb63f0, 16)             = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
    write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
    close(21)                               = 0
    close(22)                               = 0
    write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
    write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
    write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
    sendto(5, "<27>May  6 08:55:08 bluetoothd[7"..., 99, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 99
    write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
    write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
    poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}, {fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=16, events=POLLIN}, {fd=17, events=POLLIN}, {fd=18, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=20, events=POLLIN}], 16, 29838) = 2 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}, {fd=10, revents=POLLIN}])
    write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
    recvmsg(10, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=-1904749397, groups=00000002}, msg_iov(1)=[{"libudev\0\376\355\312\376(\0\0\0(\0\0\0\344\0\0\0\302\312\363\227\0\0\0\0"..., 8192}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=6456, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=0}, 0) = 268
    getrandom("\v\241<\214CLZ\366\315\360\203\375\r\277\201>", 16, GRND_NONBLOCK) = 16
    write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
    poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}, {fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=16, events=POLLIN}, {fd=17, events=POLLIN}, {fd=18, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=20, events=POLLIN}], 16, 29835) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
    read(3, "\10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16)        = 8
    poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}, {fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=16, events=POLLIN}, {fd=17, events=POLLIN}, {fd=18, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=20, events=POLLIN}], 16, 29835) = 0 (Timeout)
    read(3, 0x7ffef8cb63f0, 16)             = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
    socket(PF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_RAW, 6)       = 21
    ioctl(21, HCIGETDEVINFO, 0x7ffef8cb6330) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    sendto(5, "<27>May  6 08:55:38 bluetoothd[7"..., 67, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 67
    close(21)                               = 0
    socket(PF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_SEQPACKET, 0) = 21
    bind(21, {sa_family=AF_BLUETOOTH, sa_data="\0\0\27\276\316`S\334\0\0\0\0\0\0"}, 14) = 0
    setsockopt(21, SOL_BLUETOOTH, 4, "\1\0", 2) = 0
    fstat(21, {st_mode=S_IFSOCK|0777, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    fcntl(21, F_GETFL)                      = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
    fcntl(21, F_SETFL, O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = 0
    connect(21, {sa_family=AF_BLUETOOTH, sa_data="\21\0\2028\355\337c\210\0\0\0\0\0\0"}, 14) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
    write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
    poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}, {fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=16, events=POLLIN}, {fd=17, events=POLLIN}, {fd=18, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=20, events=POLLIN}, {fd=21, events=POLLOUT}], 17, 29971) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
    poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}, {fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=16, events=POLLIN}, {fd=17, events=POLLIN}, {fd=18, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=20, events=POLLIN}, {fd=21, events=POLLOUT}], 17, 29971) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
    read(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16)         = 8
    poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}, {fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=16, events=POLLIN}, {fd=17, events=POLLIN}, {fd=18, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=20, events=POLLIN}, {fd=21, events=POLLOUT}], 17, 29971) = 1 ([{fd=7, revents=POLLIN}])
    read(3, 0x7ffef8cb63f0, 16)             = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
    write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
    read(7, "\v\0\0\0*\0\2028\355\337c\210\0\0\0\0\0\35\0\34\tIcentre cli"..., 512) = 48
    stat("/var/lib/bluetooth/DC:53:60:CE:BE:17/cache/88:63:DF:ED:38:82", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=987, ...}) = 0
    open("/var/lib/bluetooth/DC:53:60:CE:BE:17/cache/88:63:DF:ED:38:82", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0600) = 22
    close(22)                               = 0
    open("/var/lib/bluetooth/DC:53:60:CE:BE:17/cache/88:63:DF:ED:38:82", O_RDONLY) = 22
    fstat(22, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=987, ...}) = 0
    read(22, "[General]\nName=Icentre client\342\200\231"..., 4096) = 987
    read(22, "", 4096)                      = 0
    close(22)                               = 0
    open("/var/lib/bluetooth/DC:53:60:CE:BE:17/cache/88:63:DF:ED:38:82.XYTKGY", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0666) = 22
    fallocate(22, 0, 0, 987)                = 0
    write(22, "[General]\nName=Icentre client\342\200\231"..., 987) = 987
    fstatfs(22, {f_type="EXT2_SUPER_MAGIC", f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=26647824, f_bfree=15960177, f_bavail=14600766, f_files=6782976, f_ffree=6130949, f_fsid={-697973956, -378649048}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096, f_flags=4128}) = 0
    lstat("/var/lib/bluetooth/DC:53:60:CE:BE:17/cache/88:63:DF:ED:38:82", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=987, ...}) = 0
    fsync(22)                               = 0
    close(22)                               = 0
    rename("/var/lib/bluetooth/DC:53:60:CE:BE:17/cache/88:63:DF:ED:38:82.XYTKGY", "/var/lib/bluetooth/DC:53:60:CE:BE:17/cache/88:63:DF:ED:38:82") = 0
    write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
    poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}, {fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=16, events=POLLIN}, {fd=17, events=POLLIN}, {fd=18, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=20, events=POLLIN}, {fd=21, events=POLLOUT}], 17, 0) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
    sendmsg(6, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(2)=[{"l\4\1\1<\0\0\0\220\0\0\0\206\0\0\0\1\1o\0%\0\0\0/org/blu"..., 152}, {"\21\0\0\0org.bluez.Device1\0\0\0\30\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 60}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 212
    poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}, {fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=16, events=POLLIN}, {fd=17, events=POLLIN}, {fd=18, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=20, events=POLLIN}, {fd=21, events=POLLOUT}], 17, 27825) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
    read(3, "\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16)         = 8
    poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}, {fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=16, events=POLLIN}, {fd=17, events=POLLIN}, {fd=18, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=20, events=POLLIN}, {fd=21, events=POLLOUT}], 17, 27825) = 1 ([{fd=21, revents=POLLOUT}])
    read(3, 0x7ffef8cb63f0, 16)             = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
    write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
    poll([{fd=21, events=POLLNVAL}], 1, 0)  = 0 (Timeout)
    getsockopt(21, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
    socket(PF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_SEQPACKET, 0) = 22
    bind(22, {sa_family=AF_BLUETOOTH, sa_data="\0\0\27\276\316`S\334\0\0\0\0\0\0"}, 14) = 0
    setsockopt(22, SOL_BLUETOOTH, 4, "\1\0", 2) = 0
    fstat(22, {st_mode=S_IFSOCK|0777, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    fcntl(22, F_GETFL)                      = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
    fcntl(22, F_SETFL, O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = 0
    connect(22, {sa_family=AF_BLUETOOTH, sa_data="\23\0\2028\355\337c\210\0\0\0\0\0\0"}, 14) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
    write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
    write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
    write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
    write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
    poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}, {fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=16, events=POLLIN}, {fd=17, events=POLLIN}, {fd=18, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=20, events=POLLIN}, {fd=21, events=0}, {fd=22, events=POLLOUT}], 18, 27729) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
    poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}, {fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=16, events=POLLIN}, {fd=17, events=POLLIN}, {fd=18, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=20, events=POLLIN}, {fd=21, events=0}, {fd=22, events=POLLOUT}], 18, 27729) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
    read(3, "\5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16)         = 8
    poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}, {fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=16, events=POLLIN}, {fd=17, events=POLLIN}, {fd=18, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=20, events=POLLIN}, {fd=21, events=0}, {fd=22, events=POLLOUT}], 18, 27729) = 1 ([{fd=22, revents=POLLOUT}])
    read(3, 0x7ffef8cb63f0, 16)             = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
    write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
    poll([{fd=22, events=POLLNVAL}], 1, 0)  = 0 (Timeout)
    getsockopt(22, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
    open("/var/lib/bluetooth/DC:53:60:CE:BE:17/cache/88:63:DF:ED:38:82", O_RDONLY) = 23
    fstat(23, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=987, ...}) = 0
    read(23, "[General]\nName=Icentre client\342\200\231"..., 4096) = 987
    read(23, "", 4096)                      = 0
    close(23)                               = 0
    socket(PF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_RAW, 6)       = 23
    ioctl(23, _IOC(_IOC_WRITE, 0x48, 0xc8, 0x04), 0x56438885eb30) = 0
    close(23)                               = 0
    write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
    write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
    write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
    poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}, {fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=16, events=POLLIN}, {fd=17, events=POLLIN}, {fd=18, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=20, events=POLLIN}, {fd=21, events=0}, {fd=22, events=0}], 18, 27712) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
    poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}, {fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=16, events=POLLIN}, {fd=17, events=POLLIN}, {fd=18, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=20, events=POLLIN}, {fd=21, events=0}, {fd=22, events=0}], 18, 27712) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
    read(3, "\4\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16)         = 8
    poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}, {fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=16, events=POLLIN}, {fd=17, events=POLLIN}, {fd=18, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=20, events=POLLIN}, {fd=21, events=0}, {fd=22, events=0}], 18, 27712) = 1 ([{fd=10, revents=POLLIN}])
    read(3, 0x7ffef8cb63f0, 16)             = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
    write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
    recvmsg(10, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=-278512287, groups=00000002}, msg_iov(1)=[{"libudev\0\376\355\312\376(\0\0\0(\0\0\0\361\0\0\0\302\312\363\227\0\0\0\0"..., 8192}], msg_controllen=32, [{cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS, {pid=6494, uid=0, gid=0}}], msg_flags=0}, 0) = 281
    getrandom("\253\360\30\352\346\313E\361\350|\21\5\"\32\206G", 16, GRND_NONBLOCK) = 16
    getrandom("vh\0\242\22QA\1\355G\354\304_\204`\360", 16, GRND_NONBLOCK) = 16
    readlinkat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7/2-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:05AC:030E.0019/hidraw", 0x564388863780, 99) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
    lstat("/sys", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    lstat("/sys/devices", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    lstat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    lstat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    lstat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    lstat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    lstat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7/2-7:1.0", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    lstat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7/2-7:1.0/bluetooth", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    lstat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7/2-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    lstat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7/2-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    lstat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7/2-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:05AC:030E.0019", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    lstat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7/2-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:05AC:030E.0019/hidraw", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    access("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7/2-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:05AC:030E.0019/hidraw/uevent", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    readlinkat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7/2-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:05AC:030E.0019", 0x56438885ebb0, 99) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
    lstat("/sys", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    lstat("/sys/devices", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    lstat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    lstat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    lstat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    lstat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    lstat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7/2-7:1.0", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    lstat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7/2-7:1.0/bluetooth", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    lstat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7/2-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    lstat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7/2-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    lstat("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7/2-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:05AC:030E.0019", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    access("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7/2-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:05AC:030E.0019/uevent", F_OK) = 0
    readlinkat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7/2-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:05AC:030E.0019/subsystem", "../../../../../../../../../../bu"..., 99) = 37
    open("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7/2-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:05AC:030E.0019/uevent", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 23
    fstat(23, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
    fstat(23, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
    read(23, "DRIVER=magicmouse\nHID_ID=0005:00"..., 4096) = 181
    read(23, "", 4096)                      = 0
    read(23, "", 4096)                      = 0
    close(23)                               = 0
    getrandom("\n\5\242L\273\204\177\301\36\216\363SyCp\311", 16, GRND_NONBLOCK) = 16
    open("/run/udev/data/+hid:0005:05AC:030E.0019", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    write(3, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
    poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}, {fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=16, events=POLLIN}, {fd=17, events=POLLIN}, {fd=18, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=20, events=POLLIN}, {fd=21, events=0}, {fd=22, events=0}], 18, 27701) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
    poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}, {fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=16, events=POLLIN}, {fd=17, events=POLLIN}, {fd=18, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=20, events=POLLIN}, {fd=21, events=0}, {fd=22, events=0}], 18, 27700) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
    read(3, "\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16)         = 8
    poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}, {fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=16, events=POLLIN}, {fd=17, events=POLLIN}, {fd=18, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=20, events=POLLIN}, {fd=21, events=0}, {fd=22, events=0}], 18, 27700) = 0 (Timeout)
    read(3, 0x7ffef8cb63f0, 16)             = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
    poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}, {fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=16, events=POLLIN}, {fd=17, events=POLLIN}, {fd=18, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=20, events=POLLIN}, {fd=21, events=0}, {fd=22, events=0}], 18, -1rs
    ^Cstrace: Process 727 detached
     <detached ...>
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: What is the bluetooth adapter in your system? Please add output of `lsusb` to your quetion.

Comment: Please also add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: Could this be a hardware issue with the trackpad? Is anybody else using this trackpad successfully with Ubuntu 15.10?

Comment: The trackpad works on a Lenovo notebook running Ubuntu 15.10. I have upgraded Ubuntu on my NUC to 16.04 but still have the same issue.

Comment: Thinkpad T480, Ubuntu 18.04. This fix works: https://askubuntu.com/questions/589617/apple-magic-mouse-frequently-disconnects-and-reconnects

Answer (score 2):

I had your same problem on Ubuntu 18. You're strace output looks similar to what I saw on my machine. I fixed my problem by [disabling usb auto-suspend](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#USB_autosuspend).

I was letting the kernel module handle HIDP (I think you can check this by going to `/etc/bluetooth/input.conf` and checking that `UserspaceHID` is not set to `true`), and by default the kernel would auto-suspend usb devices not in use to save power. And apparently this behavior was causing havoc with my magic trackpad.

This behavior seemed to show itself in the output of `sudo btmon`. I could see HCI sending a command to exit sniff mode (aka powersaving mode?). Sometimes it would exit successfully, transitioning into active mode and reconnecting with the trackpad. Sometimes it wouldn't, and I would see:

```
> HCI Event: Mode Change (0x14) plen 6                                                                                                                               #10952 [hci0] 807.142497
        Status: Connection Timeout (0x08)
        Handle: 256
        Mode: Active (0x00)
        Interval: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
```

And then the trackpad would stop working while the connection was reestablished. After disabling usb auto-suspend, it always stays in active mode, avoiding whatever problems were caused by entering/exiting sniff mode.

One thing the arch-wiki article skips over is how to find the correct bluetooth device in the output of `lsusb`. Perhaps it was obvious to some but not to me. So make sure to run `lsusb -v` or use `usb-devices` to get more details that make it easier to identity the device you want.

I know this question is old and I freely admit I don't totally understand all the elements of this problem, but hopefully someone will find this response helpful.

Comment: This appears to have resolved my issues with my Magic Trackpad 1 disconnecting, and maybe even with my Magic Trackpad 2 (over USB) causing kernel panics! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It may help to examine the output of `journalctl -u bluetooth.service`

I had problems with the bluetooth module in my Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga (running 15.10 -> 16.04) connecting to my Bose Soundlink Color speaker after waking from suspend, as well as some other problems like delayed and dropped audio. I picked up a [usb bluetooth adapter](http://us.creative.com/p/accessories/creative-bluetooth-audio-bt-w2-usb-transceiver) that supported some more feature sets that have been incorporated into bluetooth since my laptop was produced and it works quite well.  The bluetooth communication is between the adapter and the speaker and Ubuntu sees it as a usb device.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have thought about trying a Bluetooth dongle but really don't want to throw good money after bad. I think it should be possible for this thing to be made to work reliably as it is and that is really what I am looking for.

Comment: I agree.  Since you state that the problem takes only minutes to reoccur I would suggest you grab the process ID of the bluetooth daemon the strace the process while redirecting the output to a log file that you can use to examine what is going wrong. `ps aux|grep bluetoothd` , `strace -p $PID >> ~/bluetoothd_log`

Comment: I've added the strace.